# How can I update a custom Order field in a plugin controller?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I have a custom plugin in which I have a controller action which I want to validate some values and then update a custom field on the `Cart`.

I can get the values from the form and validate them, I'm just missing how to get them saved to the `Cart`.

I've tried the following:

```
$this->cart->setRawPostContent('orderShippingOptions', $myValue);
$this->cart->setContentFromPost('fields');
```

And also just:

```
$this->cart->setContentFromPost(['orderShippingOptions' => $myValue]);
```

I'm feel like I'm in the right area, I'm just missing something simple.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly as:

```
$cart->setContentFromPost(array( 'someKey' => $someValue ));
craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($cart);
```

(You'll need the saveOrder step as you're in your own controller, but note e.g. if you're doing this in e.g. a Commerce shipping calculator plugin, you can skip this step for efficiency reasons as a saveOrder occurs at the end of that process anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I really overthought this one! It's exactly the same as you would usually do it in Craft.

```
$this->cart->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
    'orderShippingOptions' => $myValue
));

craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($this->cart);
```

The bit I was missing was `craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($this->cart);`

Comment: Or alternatively...

        `$cart->setContentFromPost(array(
            'someKey' => $someValue
        ));`
        and then `craft()->commerce_orders->saveOrder($cart);`

Comment: Thanks Jeremy (again)! I thought I'd be pushing my luck if I asked you a follow up! This is much more succinct than mine, so if you want to add this as a proper answer, I'm happy to accept it. I'm going with this method.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the Craft 3 version of `setContentFromPost` is `setFieldValuesFromRequest`

And you can so things like:

`$order->setFieldValue("customFieldHandle", "My value");`

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-elementinterface.html#public-methods