# How do I set the value of a custom entries order field from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, entries-field, custom-field, order

I'm trying to set the value of a custom field on an order when saving an entry. I found [an example of how to do this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15165/how-can-i-update-a-custom-order-field-in-a-plugin-controller) for a simple text field, but the field I'm trying to set is an **entries** field, not just a text field. I've attempted to set the value using the following code in my entries.saveEntry event. I'm assuming I'm doing this wrong since this is an entries field, not a simple text field, but I don't know the syntax for setting content on an entries field.

```
$cart = craft()->commerce_cart->getCart();
$cart->setContentFromPost(['entriesFieldHandle' => $entry->id]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I was close. I was correct in assuming my syntax was incorrect for setting the value of an entries field.

Since an entries field is an array of elements, not just a single element, I just needed to [set the value of the field as an array](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16593/how-can-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-an-entries-field-type) instead of a string.

Changing

```
$cart->setContentFromPost(['entriesFieldHandle' => $entry->id]);
```

to

```
$cart->setContentFromPost(['entriesFieldHandle' => [$entry->id]]);
```

seemed to do the trick.

To zoom in a little more, the value needs to be set with `'entriesFieldHandle' => [$entry->id]` instead of `'entriesFieldHandle' => $entry->id`.